# How do I refresh list after delete action?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So I am fetching data through my component like `listUsers(props.page);`

This is function in my composable

```js
  const listUsers = async (payload) => {
    const result = await UserService.get(2, payload);
    data.userList = result.data.users;
    data.totalPages = result.data.total_pages
  }
```

and here is my delete function

```js
  const deleteUser = async (id) => {
    try {
      await UserService.delete(id);
      data.confirmation = !data.confirmation;

    } catch (err) {
      data.confirmation = !data.confirmation;
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

How can I use the `listUsers` function after successfull await in `deleteUser`? I want to refresh my list in component after deleting an user.

I can't use directly the listUsers function because it asks me for payload, and payload is props.page from a component..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the user from your user array:

```
const deleteUser = async (id) => {
  try {
    await UserService.delete(id);
    data.confirmation = !data.confirmation;
    data.userList = data.userList.filter(user => user.id !== id);
    // use the correct property name in your data-----^
  } catch (err) {
    data.confirmation = !data.confirmation;
    throw err;
  }
}
```

You'll have to re-calculate `data.totalPages` using the number of users and users page page.